# validation with angular checkbox-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I'm using checklist-model in my angular/electron application and have following three checkboxes.

1. Both
2. USA
3. Canada

To start with, by default '**USA**' is checked, however if the user clicks on '**Both**' or '**Canada**' , I need to check for a specific flag, and if the flag is false, I need to alert the user and avoid '**Both**' or '**Canada**' being clicked.

```
<div style="height:115px;background-color:#FBF9EC" class="form-control" >
            <label ng-repeat="item in locations" style="width:80%">
                    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="locationData.item" checklist-value="item" checklist-before-change="checkListvalidate(item)" ng-change="checkBoxClickFunc(item)" ng-click="locationClick()"> 
                    {{item}} 
            </label>
        </div>

In the controller:
$scope.locationClick = function(){
     if(!myFlag){
          return false;
     }
};
```

The spec for **checklist-before-change** says

> An angular expression evaluated each time before the checklist-model has changed. If it evaluates to 'false' then the model will not change anymore.

What is it that I'm not doing correctly ....

Answer (score 0):

You have many listeners in the checkedbox input :

- `checklist-before-change="checkListvalidate(item)"`
- `ng-change="checkBoxClickFunc(item)"`
- `ng-click="locationClick()"`

I think these are too much to address your need and besides, it complicates the understand of the logic and it may create side-effects.
Why not use only `checklist-before-change` directive and make the call to `locationClick()` inside it ? 
 I think it should be enough.

Here an example :

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div style="height:115px;background-color:#FBF9EC" class="form-control" >
            <label ng-repeat="item in locations" style="width:80%">
                    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="locationData.item" 
                           checklist-value="item" checklist-before-change="checkListvalidate(item)" > 
                    {{item}} 
            </label>
        </div>
  </body>
```